# Running a .sh file without root

Tags: bash, games, root

I've recently downloaded a game (Mark of the Ninja from Humble Bundle 9 to be exact) to play on Ubuntu. From what I can tell after extracting the game, it is stand-alone and doesn't require installation on the computer you want to play it on (I want to play it off my flash drive at university). However, as I don't have root access on the computers at university, I can't use `chmod +x ninja-bin` to allow executing the main ninja-bin.sh file as a program instead of opening it in gedit. Also, when I try executing it via the terminal using `./ninja-bin` I get `bash: ./ninja-bin: Permission denied`. Is there any workaround for this for which I don't need root access? Or should I just not try to play games on a computer which I don't have root for?

Thanks

Comment: `chmod` is usually not restricted to privileged users. If your university does not allow you to execute arbitrary files, you probably should not run the game.

Comment: So I spoke to some friends of mine, and it turned out that the issue was that the game was on my flash drive - apparently marking files as executable doesn't work so well on the FAT format. So I've copied the game to my home folder on the network here, and I can `chmod +x` and execute the binaries just fine. Only now I get the message `ERROR: Missing required OpenGL extensions.` which probably isn't something I can fix, with me not being an admin and all...

Thanks so much for your help, guys!

Answer (score 2):

If you are not a member of `sudo` group and if your access to `chmod` command was blocked, then there is nothing that you can do. Due to these reasons Linux like systems are known for their security.

Or, maybe you can do something: convince the admin (root) to change the permissions for that file :).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, run it with `sudo`:

```
sudo ./ninja-bin
```

I suppose the elevated rights are required during install procedure.

Comment: and what password should they enter?

Comment: Enter your user password.